# Pairs which are Divisible by 4

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I am practicing coding problems on GeeksforGeeks and there I got this problem, I tried to solve the question, but I failed to do so. So I saw the code, but I am unable to understand the logic behind it. I am also putting the solution code, anyone who understand please explain this to me.

> Given an array, if ‘n’ positive integers, count the number of pairs of
> integers in the array that have the sum divisible by 4.
>
> Example 1:
>
> Input : Arr[] = {2, 2, 1, 7, 5}
> Output : 3
> Explanation:
> (2,2), (1,7) and(7,5) are the 3 pairs.
>
> Example 2:
>
> Input : Arr[] = {2, 2, 3, 5, 6}
> Output : 4
>
> Your Task:
> This is a function problem. The input is already taken care of by the
> driver code. You only need to complete the function
> count4Divisibiles() that takes an array (arr), sizeOfArray (n), and
> return the number of pairs. The driver code takes care of the
> printing.
>
> Expected Time Complexity: O(N).
> Expected Auxiliary Space: O(1).
>
> Constraints:
>
> 1 ≤ N ≤ 105
>
> 1 ≤ arr[] ≤ 105

Solution for the problem

> ```
> // Java program to count pairs 
> // whose sum divisible by '4' 
>
> import java.util.*; 
>
> class Count{ 
>   public static int count4Divisibiles(int arr[] , 
>                                           int n ) 
>   { 
>       // Create a frequency array to count 
>       // occurrences of all remainders when 
>       // divided by 4 
>       int freq[] = {0, 0, 0, 0}; 
>       int i = 0; 
>       int ans; 
>       
>       // Count occurrences of all remainders 
>       for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
>               ++freq[arr[i] % 4]; 
>       
>       //If both pairs are divisible by '4' 
>       ans = freq[0] * (freq[0] - 1) / 2; 
>   
>       // If both pairs are 2 modulo 4 
>       ans += freq[2] * (freq[2] - 1) / 2; 
>   
>       // If one of them is equal 
>       // to 1 modulo 4 and the 
>       // other is equal to 3 
>       // modulo 4 
>       ans += freq[1] * freq[3]; 
>   
>       return (ans); 
>   } 
>   public static void main(String[] args) 
>   { 
>       int arr[] = {2, 2, 1, 7, 5}; 
>       int n = 5; 
>       System.out.print(count4Divisibiles(arr, n)); 
>   } 
> }
> ```

Comment: Try using a debugger, or try adding print statements. You learn programming by programming. In this case: by running code, and trying to get insight into how it works. So please dont expect us to do that for you. Beyond that, step back: look at the comments, and really research what each of them means. This is a math problem, so you better understand the the math terms and **concepts** used here. Meaning: basically this code uses clever math tricks to achieve the desired outcome. There isnt much explaining of code required. but understanding of maths.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have the following numbers -

`4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12`

Now when is a number divisible by 4? Of course when the `MOD` is `0`. So if you have 2 numbers giving you `MOD` `0`, you can pair them up.

In the above array, you have `4, 8, 12` which will give you `MOD` 0. How many pairs you can get from these 3?

`3C2 -> (3 * (3-1)) / 2`

Similarly, you can pair `6, 10`, because `6` will give you `MOD` `2` and `10` will also give you `MOD` `2`. Combining these, you will get a number which is divisible by `4`

Finally, you can pair numbers giving `MOD` `1` and `MOD` `3`. Because the sum of these pairs would be divisible by `4`. If you have X many `MOD` `1` and Y many `MOD` `3`, you can make `X * Y` number of pairs.

Comment: i am understanding these thing here function is returning ans variable which is being calculate out of the freq array, that is the thing i am unable to understand.

Comment: it's counting the frequency of MOD values. If you have  frequency of 0 is 5. It means you have 5 numbers which are divisible by 5. If you have the frequency of 1 is 3, it means you have 3 numbers which MOD value is 1 (for example 5, 9, 13 )